# How to access subclasses in one project where superclass is in other project without importing .h file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a base product(`Base_Product`) which defines a base class (`Base`).In another project(`ProjectA`)which add as a target to base product, I extend the Base and Create Derived class of it (`DerivedA`).Similarly I have one more project(`ProjectB`) which also derives a Class (`DerivedB`) from `Base`.
In My Base product I have A `FactoryClass` with FactroryMethod like this:

```
#import "DerivedA.h"
#import "DerivedB.h"

@implementation FactoryClass
    +(Base *)factMeth:(int select){
    switch select{
    case 1: return [DerivedA new];
            break;
    case 2: return [DerivedB new];
            break;
    default: break;
    }
@end
```

My issue is, I need to import `DerivedA.h` and `DerivedB.h` in `FactoryClass.m` file. Suppose in future I need to add `DerivedC`(which extend the Base) in `ProjectC`(A new project add as a target to Base_Product), then I need to add `DerivedC.h`also into `FactoryClass.m` in Base_product, but its not supposed to be do as per my use case. Base product remains unchanged and should allow future extensions on it. So I need to avoid importing of `DerivedA.h` and `DerivedB.h` in `FactoryClass.m`
I have tried  header search  path but its not solve the issue. Any help to avoid the importing of all subclasses??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could 'register' your derived class names as `NSString` in your `FactoryClass` class and then use `[NSClassFromString(@"DerivedClassName") new]` to dynamically instantiate the derived class.

```
@interface FactoryClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *derived;
@end

@implementation FactoryClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _derived = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)registerClass:(NSString*)clazz forIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    [self.derived setObject:clazz forKey:@(index)];
}

- (BaseClass*)build:(NSInteger)index
{
    BaseClass *base = [[NSClassFromString(self.derived[@(index)]) alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"base = %@", [base description]);
    return base;
}

@end
```